# Passing PlusClient object through activities

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus

I'm implementing the Google+ login in my first activity, then in another activity I need to publish something by pressing on a button. The login on the first activity works perfectly, but I need the PlusClient object in the other activity because i need it to publish with PlusShare.build(...). How can i pass or construct again the PlusClient object through the two activities????

here is the code of the method that share the content:

```
public void onGoogleButtonClick(int position) {

    if(mPlusClient.isConnected()){
    Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this, mPlusClient)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setText("Hey +"+usersInLab.get(position).getIdGoogle()+"! I'm at the JOL Lab!")
            .getIntent();

    startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
    }else{
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not logged in Google+", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Using the ID of a friend in the text i need to build the PlusShare with my PlusClient object but in this activity i have not a PlusClient object because I implemented it with all methods (onConnected(), onConnectionFailed(),...) in the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code. Its working for me. Hope it will helpful to you

```
enter code here
  Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(getActivity())
                .setType("text/plain").setText(shareDescription)
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://" + shareURL)).getIntent();
  startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);

        `enter code here
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I need to share a post with a friend whose I know the google id with this call: usersInLab.get(position).getIdGoogle()